# How to make resizable and movable composite in jface?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to add three composite to my screen for that I am using fill layout which will divide the composite in the equal ratio.  Now if I want to add composite in different ratio, which layout should I use?

And I want to make my composites movable and re-sizable. How can I do so?
I had tried all the layout but  the composites are not re-sizable.

```
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
        parent.setTouchEnabled(true);
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP);
        container.setTouchEnabled(true);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        {
            Composite composite = new Composite(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.EMBEDDED);
            composite.setTouchEnabled(true);
            composite.layout();
        }
        {
            Composite composite = new Composite(container, SWT.BORDER);
            composite.setTouchEnabled(true);
        }

        Composite composite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
        return container;
    }
```

Comment: If you mean you want to drag the composites to move or size them that is difficult. There is no standard SWT/JFace code to do that. There is `Sash` and `SashForm` that provide some sizing.

Comment: I tried with Sash Form , but faced the same problem.i want to add three composite to my screen in different ratio if i am using fill layout it is getting set in same ratio. And how to make the composite re-sizable during the run time.